# How do I conditionally build .Net Core 3.0 only if supported by tooling?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild, conditional-compilation, target-framework

I would like to use the TargetFrameworks .csproj element to multi-target both .Net Core 3.0 (netcoreapp3.0) and .Net Framework 4.8 (net48) for a console application, like so:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.0;net48</TargetFrameworks>
        <AssemblyName>MyConsoleApp</AssemblyName>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

However, I would like the same .csproj file to degrade gracefully in older tooling and compile *only* .Net Framework 4.8 when the tooling does not support netcoreapp3.0 (such as with Visual Studio 2017).

I reviewed the conditional compilation documentation, but it seems to talk only about changing settings *when* compiling, not whether to do the compilation in the first place.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Hi David, any update for this issue? Since your project always target at least .net framework 4.8, it's not recommended to use `dotnet build` command from .net core sdk, You can consider using the msbuild package. And if you've found the workaround yourself, please feel free to share here as an answer, that will help members with similar issue :)

Comment: Thanks @LanceLi-MSFT, unfortunately no, this is a side project and will likely get back to it on the weekend. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: You're welcome, any update feel free to share here:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I reviewed the conditional compilation documentation, but it seems to
> talk only about changing settings when compiling, not whether to do
> the compilation in the first place.

Yes, [msbuild conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2019) should work **inside** the `<Project>` node. For your requirement, I can only imagine one possible way that you add the `conditions` to the first `PropertyGroup`( `Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)'=='16.0'"`), something similar to this format:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)'=='16.0'">
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.0;net48</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)'!='16.0'">
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- ... other PropertyGroup with conditions-->

  <!--I use this script to confirm that when building the project in VS2017(msbuild15.0),the VS version is 15.0 while in VS2019(msbuild16.0), VS version is 16.0-->
  <Target Name="TestVersion" AfterTargets="build">
    <Message Text="version=>$(VisualStudioVersion)" Importance="high"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Have to say most of the time, we use Multi-targets for class library projects instead of console projects, not sure about your specific reason to do this... Hope it makes some help :)

**Update:**

To build `.net` projects when VS is not installed, we can consider using `Build Tools for VS package`, here's the link of [build tools for VS2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)(contains the msbuild 16.0). In `All downloads=>Tools for VS2019` we can find the build tools package.

To make sure we can use the msbuild.exe from this package to build .net framework4.8 and .net core3.0 console projects, make sure we enabled these workloads and components when installing:

[image]

[image]

We can navigate to `Individual Components` to make sure .net core 3.0 and .net 4.8 is enabled.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at that, but wondered if it would work outside of Visual Studio (e.g. "dotnet build" in the common case, not the fallback). Re: use case, in our OSS project, we want to support console app developers who might not be able, yet, to upgrade to VS 2019 (corporate policies, etc). Our library is netstandard2.0, so works both ways out of the box.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if `dotnet build` works well for this situation(out of box), see [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build), the `dotnet build` command is something more related to `.net core` while most of the time your project also targets `.net framework 4.8`.  To get it work well outside of VS, you can consider `msbuild`. There's one [Build Tools for VS](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) package which provides the ability to build .net framework and .net core project in build server though VS is not installed. Maybe it can help...

Comment: This solution seems to get me what I need, but still need to validate on VS 2017. I ended up using the following logic: if the VS Version is 16.0 or higher or non existant, i.e. Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)'&gt;='16.0' or '$(VisualStudioVersion)'==''", build both frameworks, otherwise, build 4.8 only, i.e. Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)'&lt;'16.0'". (As an aside, after doing some reading I learned that 'dotnet build' uses msbuild. If someone wants to use "full msbuild", they can specify the 'dotnet msbuild' command.)

Comment: Good hint! Actually the script above is a simple sample, we.can easily modify it to make our logic depending on what we need:)

Comment: Confirmed building only net48 on VS 2017. Thanks for your help, @Lance Li-MSFT